# Nothing happens on Sign In page

Tags: php, authentication, sign

I am trying to make a login page for my website, but when I press the login button, nothing happens. Help Please!

Here is the code i'm using for the login page (This is just a snippet, yes I do have the basic HTML tags)

```
<center><form action="login.php" method="post"></form></center>
<br>
<center><input type="text" name="username"></center>
<br>
<center><input type="password" name="password"></center>
<br>
<center><input type="submit" name="button" value="Login"></center>
```

This is `login.php`

```
<?php

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    include ("connect.php");

    if($username && $password)
    {
        //info is provided
    }
    else
    {
        echo "You did not provide the proper information needed for login.";
        include ("signin.html");
    }

?>
```

this is `connect.php`

```
<?php

    $connect = mysql_connect("*****", "*****", "*****");
    mysql_select_db("******");

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have a the closing `</form>` tag immediately after the opening tag effectively closing the form and making the rest of it invalid and inoperable. Move it to the end of your form and it will work.

Comment: This worked great. But now im getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in /public_html/login.php on line 12

Comment: The code you posted looks correct. Make sure you aren't missing a semi-colon on the previous line.

Comment: Weird. I was missing it. I inserted it and it still gives me this error.

Comment: Something in that code above the else statement is incorrect. Since I can't see it all I can say is keep removing pieces until the error goes away. Then you'll know what code is causing the problem.

Comment: That is the whole connect.php, not sure what you mean by cant see it all. What else do you need to see

Comment: No, the error is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in /public_html/login.php on line 12

Answer (score 0):

Try Updated code

```
 <center><form action="login.php" method="post">
                    <br>
                       <center><input type="text" name="username"></center>
                       <br>
                       <center><input type="password" name="password"></center>
                       <br>
                       <center><input type="submit" name="button" value="Login"></center>
     </form></center>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly make changes in your template.It should be like this...

```
<center><form action="login.php" method="post">
  <br>
  <center><input type="text" name="username"></center>
  <br>
  <center><input type="password" name="password"></center>
  <br>
 <center><input type="submit" name="button" value="Login"></center>
</form></center>
```